# Recording audio with a mic on Android

Tags: android, audio, microphone, smartphone

I am developing an Android application which is supposed to capture audio with the built-in mic of the smartphone and save it.

For the further processing purposes I would like to have some control over the quality of audio captured. For instance, to my knowledge some smartphones have high-quality audio recording mode and I would like to make use of it, if that is possible.

I am aware of `mediaRecorder`, but I am not sure how to use its methods or input arguments to get the best quality of sound possible. I would be very grateful if somebody could point out that for me or provide references to other libraries that allow to adjust the quality of recorded sound.

Comment: This might help https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/audio-capture.html

Comment: Well, I have seen this code and it works totally fine for me, but I am wondering if there is a library which would, say, allow me adjusting the sampling frequency, for example...

Comment: You should be able to change the encoder to a higher quality format https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.html  I'm not certain about specific frequencies however

Comment: Thank you, overlooked this, it might be useful.

Comment: Happy to help! Best of luck